# javax ConstraintViolation: How to identify violated element of a Set?

Tags: java, validation, constraints

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
  @NotNull String propertyA;
}
class B {
  @Valid java.util.List<A> list;
  @Valid java.util.Map<Integer, A> map;
  @Valid java.util.Set<A> set;
}

B b = ...
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation
    .buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
validator.validate(b);
```

Lets assume the properties `list`, `map` and `set` of `b` all contained one instance of `A` where `propertyA` was `null` and therefore violated. The result of the `validate(b)` call would result in a set of `ConstraintViolation` with three violations which have the following `PropertyPath`:

```
Node{name=list,inIterable=false}
   -> Node{name=propertyA,inIterable=true,index=0,key=null}

Node{name=map,inIterable=false}
   -> Node{name=propertyA,inIterable=true,index=null,key=0}

Node{name=set,inIterable=false}
   -> Node{name=propertyA,inIterable=true,index=null,key=null}
```

In the path for the `list` property, the second node contains the `index` property to identify the violated element of the `List`. Likewise, the path for the `map` property has the violated key in the second node. However, there is no information which element is violated in the path for the `set` property. I expected to get the violated element as `key` or as a third Node property `Node.setElement`, or something like this.

When there is more than one element in the `Set`, how can the violated element of that Set be identified?